# Reset parameters of a neural network in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch, gated-recurrent-unit

I have a neural network with the following structure:

```
class myNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.bigru = nn.GRU(input_size=2, hidden_size=100, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(200, 32)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc1.weight)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 2)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc2.weight)
```

I need to reinstate the model to an unlearned state by resetting the parameters of the neural network. I can do so for `nn.Linear` layers by using the method below:

```
def reset_weights(self):
    torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc1.weight)
    torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc2.weight)
```

But, to reset the weight of the `nn.GRU` layer, I could not find any such snippet.

My question is how does one reset the `nn.GRU` layer? Any other way of resetting the network is also fine. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: see the official pytorch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-re-set-alll-parameters-in-a-network/20819/10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `reset_parameters` method on the layer. As given [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/reinitializing-the-weights-after-each-cross-validation-fold/11034/2?u=dishin_goyani)

```
for layer in model.children():
   if hasattr(layer, 'reset_parameters'):
       layer.reset_parameters()
```

Or Another way would be saving the model first and then reload the module state. Using `torch.save` and `torch.load` [see docs for more](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/serialization.html#saving-and-loading-torch-nn-modules) Or  [Saving and Loading Models](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-and-loading-models)

Comment: it does not walk into nested nn.ModuleList(). The best way is reorganize the code to recreate whole network instance.

Comment: With recursion, this works for more complex models as well: https://pastebin.com/QBuNyYuc

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code with an example that runs:

```
def lp_norm(mdl: nn.Module, p: int = 2) -> Tensor:
    lp_norms = [w.norm(p) for name, w in mdl.named_parameters()]
    return sum(lp_norms)

def reset_all_weights(model: nn.Module) -> None:
    """
    refs:
        - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-re-set-alll-parameters-in-a-network/20819/6
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63627997/reset-parameters-of-a-neural-network-in-pytorch
        - https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html
    """

    @torch.no_grad()
    def weight_reset(m: nn.Module):
        # - check if the current module has reset_parameters & if it's callabed called it on m
        reset_parameters = getattr(m, "reset_parameters", None)
        if callable(reset_parameters):
            m.reset_parameters()

    # Applies fn recursively to every submodule see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html
    model.apply(fn=weight_reset)


def reset_all_linear_layer_weights(model: nn.Module) -> nn.Module:
    """
    Resets all weights recursively for linear layers.

    ref:
        - https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html
    """

    @torch.no_grad()
    def init_weights(m):
        if type(m) == nn.Linear:
            m.weight.fill_(1.0)

    # Applies fn recursively to every submodule see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html
    model.apply(init_weights)


def reset_all_weights_with_specific_layer_type(model: nn.Module, modules_type2reset) -> nn.Module:
    """
    Resets all weights recursively for linear layers.

    ref:
        - https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html
    """

    @torch.no_grad()
    def init_weights(m):
        if type(m) == modules_type2reset:
            # if type(m) == torch.nn.BatchNorm2d:
            #     m.weight.fill_(1.0)
            m.reset_parameters()

    # Applies fn recursively to every submodule see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html
    model.apply(init_weights)


# -- tests

def reset_params_test():
    import torchvision.models as models
    from uutils.torch_uu import lp_norm

    resnet18 = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
    resnet18_random = models.resnet18(pretrained=False)

    print(f'{lp_norm(resnet18)=}')
    print(f'{lp_norm(resnet18_random)=}')
    print(f'{lp_norm(resnet18)=}')
    reset_all_weights(resnet18)
    print(f'{lp_norm(resnet18)=}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reset_params_test()
    print('Done! \a\n')
```

output:

```
lp_norm(resnet18)=tensor(517.5472, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
lp_norm(resnet18_random)=tensor(668.3687, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
lp_norm(resnet18)=tensor(517.5472, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
lp_norm(resnet18)=tensor(476.0836, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
Done!
```

I am assuming this works because I calculated the norm twice for the pre-trained net and it was the same both times before calling reset.

Though I was unhappy it wasn't closer to the norm of the random net I must admit but I think this is good enough.

same: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-re-set-alll-parameters-in-a-network/20819/11

Answer (score 0):

New to pytorch, I wonder if this could be a solution :)

Suppose Model inherents from torch.nn.module,

to reset it to zeros:

```py
dic = Model.state_dict()
for k in dic:
    dic[k] *= 0
Model.load_state_dict(dic)
del(dic)
```

to reset it randomly

```py
dic = Model.state_dict()
for k in dic:
    dic[k] = torch.randn(dic[k].size())  
Model.load_state_dict(dic)
del(dic)
```